# Qt - Scroll bar contrast - can it be increased?

Tags: qt, editor, scrollbar, contrast

I am asking about the text editor. I am not talking about programming a scroll bar. I’ve searched online and found millions of help about programming scroll bars and text areas, but I want to change the color of the scroll bars in the Qt Creator text editor itself. I found the font and background color scheme amendment but could not find anything about the coloration of the scroll bars. I don’t know whether any body else has the same problem but my scroll bar tablet (the thing you slide up and down) is white and the area above and below it is mainly white (very slightly off-white). But you can’t really see any contrast, and I often can’t see where the tablet is. If anybody knows if it can be amended – please help. Or is it just a fixture of Qt 5.2.0 that is difficult and annoying?

Comment: Why not using Style Sheets? -> http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Create file with styles

//qtcreator.css

```
QMainWindow,    
     QScrollBar {
        background: #32CC99;
    }
```

Next run QtCreator in the following way:

```
qtcreator.exe -stylesheet path/to/your/style/qtcreator.css
```

Also check the link:
[Qt Creator styling](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtCreatorStyling)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yes adding a -stylesheet option to the command line that brings up Qt Creator is the way to do it.

qtcreator -stylesheet /path/to/your/style/qtcreator.css

I shall experiment with different options in the stylesheet.
Thanks to mhcuervo and Kamil.

Comment: this should go into a comment, not a solution

Comment: @Clive please remove this from answer list and add it as an comment, the question itself is relevant but conversation using answers  is not permitted

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately if I even hint at a stylesheet the drop-list bars at the top go white.  Even if I refer to a stylesheet and don't mention visual items in it.  See here what it looks like [title bar partly gone white]  billionmessages.com/clivesmart/gone_white.png

As you can see, some of the title bars - especially the one that allows the selection of Projects, Open documents, File system, etc - have gone white, unlike the dark gray ones that is the normal color of them.  Is this some inconsistency in how Creator is written?  In my attached pic I have ringed round the offending bars in red.

I've found I can add .css to change the vertical scroll bar as desired, but this other fault is not a scroll bar, so shouldn't be affected.

I've even given a stylesheet as an empty file, and still Creator mucks up the titles, at least with "Vim (dark)" as the Color Scheme.  Try it yourself.  Let me know it you get the same hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Exercise caution when applying styles, as overriding the existing styling may make some items difficult to see. Also, setting a stylesheet may affect the text editor color scheme and the styling of the integrated Qt Designer.
For example:

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
     border: 2px  ;
     width: 15px;
     margin: 22px 0 22px 0;
 }
 QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
     background: black;
     min-height: 20px;
 }
```

It will also require a change and

```
QAbstractScrollArea {
     background: #050505;
}
```